# Let's revisit Roman numbers

Tags: java, object-oriented, programming-challenge, unit-testing, roman-numerals

**Problem Statement:**

> Write a function to convert from normal numbers to Roman Numerals:
>   e.g.

```
 1  => I
10  => X
 7  => VII
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class RomanNumeral {
  private final int number;
  private static final Map<Integer, String> CACHE = new HashMap<>();

  private static final NavigableMap<Integer, String> NUMBER_TO_ROMAN =
      initMap();

  public RomanNumeral(int number) {
    if (number < 0 || number > 3000) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number out of range.");
    }
    this.number = number;
  }

  public String getRomanNumeral() {
    if (number == 0) {
      return "";
    }
    String result = CACHE.get(number);
    if (result != null) {
      return result;
    }
    result = toRomen(number);
    CACHE.put(number, result);
    return result;
    //return number == 0 ? "" : toRomen(number);
  }

  private static String toRomen(int num) {
    int floorNum = NUMBER_TO_ROMAN.floorKey(num);
    // Base case
    if (floorNum == num) {
      return NUMBER_TO_ROMAN.get(num);
    }
    return NUMBER_TO_ROMAN.get(floorNum) + toRomen(num - floorNum);
  }

  private static NavigableMap<Integer, String> initMap() {
    NavigableMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put(1, "I");
    map.put(4, "IV");
    map.put(5, "V");
    map.put(9, "IX");
    map.put(10, "X");
    map.put(40, "XL");
    map.put(50, "L");
    map.put(90, "XC");
    map.put(100, "C");
    map.put(400, "CD");
    map.put(500, "D");
    map.put(900, "CM");
    map.put(1000, "M");
    return map;
  }
}
```

**Test Suite:**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class RomanNumeralsTest {

    private int input;
    private String expectedOutput;

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {0, ""},
                {1, "I"},
                {2, "II"},
                {3, "III"},
                {4, "IV"},
                {5, "V"},
                {6, "VI"},
                {9, "IX"},
                {27, "XXVII"},
                {48, "XLVIII"},
                {59, "LIX"},
                {93, "XCIII"},
                {141, "CXLI"},
                {163, "CLXIII"},
                {402, "CDII"},
                {575, "DLXXV"},
                {911, "CMXI"},
                {1024, "MXXIV"},
                {3000, "MMM"}
        });
    }

    public RomanNumeralsTest(int input, String expectedOutput) {
        this.input = input;
        this.expectedOutput = expectedOutput;
    }

    @Test
    public void convertArabicNumberalToRomanNumeral() {
        RomanNumeral romanNumeral = new RomanNumeral(input);

        assertEquals(expectedOutput, romanNumeral.getRomanNumeral());
    }
}
```

**Design Discussion:**

- I have used `TreeMap` as the keys are **ordered**.
- I played a bit with `CACHING` here since I didn't want to do the same computation again and again.

**Reference:**

http://exercism.io/exercises/java/roman-numerals/readme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is very clear and nicely written. Also, using a `TreeMap` to take advantage of ordered keys is great insight.

Overall, I practically only have good comments about the code:

- Throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` in case of a negative or greater than 3000 number is a great way to document the fact those values are not allowed.
- The recursive method `toRomen` handles all the case correctly. You made a small typo in the name of the method: it should be `toRoman` instead of `toRomen`.
- Coding against the `NavigableMap` interface and hiding the `TreeMap` concrete instantiation inside a method is a nice thing to do.
- Using a cache might indeed be a good idea: it helps to ensure that the same roman numerals are not converted each time and, since we're only interested in 3000 numbers at maximum, this map won't become gigantic and consume a lot of memory.

---

I still have a couple of suggestions:

- You are currently handling the number 0 in a special early return inside `getRomanNumeral` with:

  ```
  if (number == 0) {
      return "";
  }
  ```

  This isn't strictly needed. You have done that because `toRomen` doesn't handle 0 as input. Handling 0 could be done inside `toRomen` instead. Consider the following:

  ```
  private static String toRoman(int num) {
      if (num == 0) {
          return "";
      }
      int floorNum = NUMBER_TO_ROMAN.floorKey(num);
      return NUMBER_TO_ROMAN.get(floorNum) + toRoman(num - floorNum);
  }
  ```

  Now the method `toRoman` has a clear-cut base case: when the number given is 0, we return an empty String. This also takes care of the recursive call with `num - floorNum` when both are equal: we will fall under this case and return the empty String.
- With the above change, `getRomanNumeral` now becomes:

  ```
  public String getRomanNumeral() {
      String result = CACHE.get(number);
      if (result != null) {
          return result;
      }
      result = toRomen(number);
      CACHE.put(number, result);
      return result;
  }
  ```

  We could use methods introduced in Java 8 to make this shorter. Mainly, we're interested in the [`computeIfAbsent(key, mappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method here. This method will return the currently mapped value to the given key, or invoke the given mapping function if there are no mapping. Therefore, we can simply have here:

  ```
  public String getRomanNumeral() {
      return CACHE.computeIfAbsent(number, RomanNumeral::toRoman);
  }
  ```

  When the cache already contains the value for `number`, it will be returned directly. Otherwise, the method `toRoman` will be invoked by giving it the number as parameter, the cache will be updated with the value returned by the function and this value will be returned.

Comment: Overall a good suggestion for base case but still I would prefer to handle `0` outside the recursive function because it allows me dodge several computations like cache checking and calling recursive function. I really liked the idea for changing base case and it makes code more readable.